# Rsync and dynamic exclude

Tags: bash, shell, loops, rsync

i'm trying to make this little script work, but i'm missing something..

```
exclude=""
while read line
do
    exclude+="--exclude $line "
done < exclude.ini
echo "$exclude"
"rsync -rvi --delete $exclude /var/www/$1 /var/export"
```

The script is reading the files that needs to exclude from a file, but i'm not able to concatenate properly those string

The entries in the file are written like this
.svn
_svn
.htaccess
ReadAndDeleteMe.ini
cache/*
documentation

anyone can help ?

Comment: What does `echo "$exclude"` print? Also if you have wildcards in there that could cause a problem with shell expansion. And finally I think the final line should be `eval "rsync...."` so the expression is evaluated.

Comment: It prints part of the text taken from the file.. I still needto test the provided solution by @enzotib, but I suppose that it may be the solution I was searching for.. Man pages always help in the end :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
--exclude-from=exclude.ini
```

In fact the man page says:

```
   --exclude-from=FILE
          This option is related to the --exclude option, but it specifies
          a FILE that contains exclude patterns  (one  per  line).   Blank
          lines  in  the  file  and  lines  starting  with  ’;’ or ’#’ are
          ignored.  If FILE is -, the list  will  be  read  from  standard
          input.
```